# How to make the images in horizontal row to move up?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move my horizontal row of images up a few pixels. How do I go about this? I'm a newbie.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is your code?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: pls post your code or jsfiddle

Answer (score -1):

This is my sample image. dont mind the mind blowing series of letters and numbers :)  It is just a src code.

To move your images up a few pixels you should use the `transform` css style.
Its up to you if you want to set it in a class or id or directly in the `img` element as shown below. and set `translateY([value]px)` and your good to go..

Setting it to negative number of pixels will move the element or your image upward and otherwise if positive.

I hope it satisfies you. :)
Welcome to SO....

```css
img
{
  transform:translateY(-50px)
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
```

Answer (score -2):

see if this works for you

```css
.row img{
  border: 1px solid #111;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.row1 img{
  bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
.row2 img{
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row1">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    some text
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    some text
  </div>

</div>

<hr/>

<div class="row row2">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    some text
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    some text
  </div>

</div>
```